# PHP - Cutting filenames

Tags: php

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I have filenames being outputted by my database in the following type of format

> filename-144x96.jpg
>
> filename-144x180.jpg
>
> file-name-144x180.jpg

etc etc etc

Is there a way that i can ditch everything including and after the last - ??

So that after it processed, the filenames would be

filename.jpg

filename.jpg

file-name.jpg

Im having some trouble trying to figure this one out.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$filename = "file-name-1440x80.jpg";
 echo preg_replace("/-\d+x\d+/i","", $filename);
// prints file-name.jpg

?>
```

Comment: The filenames that come from the database are dynamic, so a static solution like thins wouldnt work ... it needs to be a one fit all solution, if that makes sense

Comment: Updated, just make sure to assign $filename so it's from the database.

Comment: I would add a $ to the end of the regexp to make sure it only matched at the end of the filename.

Comment: That would make sense if I was trying to match the string with regex, however I am using this regex as a replace, so anything it matches will get replaced with "".